# Internet Explorer 8 issues with WordPress 3.8

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

I am working on a WordPress 3.8 website. The site runs great on Chrome and Firefox and IE9+. While I know a lot of people may say drop support for IE8.. thats not an option being that 50% of our customers that view the website are running Windows XP with IE8.

If you take a look at www.dontbebroke.com/redesign

One major issue with IE8 is that for some reason the menu is not loading. I have a jsfiddle setup at http://jsfiddle.net/9nTg3/10/ for the menu but unfortunately I can even get JSFiddle to load on my Windows XP with IE8 computer that I am using for testing. Using the debug tools I have the only Error I get about the menu is the following:

```
  Line: 0
  Character: 0
  Code: 0
  Error Message: Script Error
  URL: http://www.dontbebroke.com/redesign/wp-content/themes/js/jquery.sliding_menu.js
```

If I could get help with that one that would be great.

I have Modernizr, Selectivir running if its IE6 or IE8.

I am not sure what else I can do, all tips and hints will be greatly useful, I also apologize if this is TOO BROAD of a topic, I just haven't been getting anywhere with Google.

Comment: It's not too broad, you just haven't really given us anything that will help us diagnose the problem. you need to narrow it down to a specific example that can be included in the question.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I would of loved to provide code but besides the menu  not loading that was really the only major example I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a jsfiddle setup at http://jsfiddle.net/9nTg3/10/ for the menu but unfortunately I can even get JSFiddle to load on my Windows XP with IE8 computer

Yes, the whole jsfiddle editor environment is not compatible with older IE.

But when you call just the output document of your fiddle, using http://jsfiddle.net/9nTg3/10/show/, you can get that to show just fine in IE 8, and you will get an error message

```
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number
```

pertaining to line #80 of your document, which contains

```
$('<div/>', { id: 'sliding_menu_js', class: 'cerrado' }).appendTo('body');
```

`class` is considered a “reserved word” in JavaScript (although it is not actually used in the language), and older IE seem to be stricter about that than other browsers – so you have to put it into quotes to use it as an object key:

```
$('<div/>', { id: 'sliding_menu_js', 'class': 'cerrado' }).appendTo('body');
```

should work.

(And line #82 contains the same mistake again.)

---

Edit: There are a few more errors, f.e. you still have `<?PHP … ?>` code in your fiddle, you have a `body` element in there (which makes it end up having two bodies, since jsfiddle inserts that element for you) – and you forgot to close the top-most `<div>`.

With that all fixed, the menu shows up in IE 8 as well: http://jsfiddle.net/9nTg3/17/show/
(Obviously without transparency and shadow, but it shows up nonetheless.)

Comment: That worked :) 

Does IE8 not like percentage widths? for example this page looks like hell on IE8 http://dontbebroke.com/redesign/?page_id=130

Comment: Well first of all you should stop [writing HTML “like hell”](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://dontbebroke.com/redesign/?page_id=130) :-) … go fix your HTML errors first of all. After that you can go looking for the reasons of displaying errors.

Comment: Actually most of those are from WordPress and the SEO plugin by Yoast I have been going through the process of fixing all those.